# Find pixels with given RGB colors

Tags: python, colors

I would like to get all coordinates from the pixels with a given RGB color in Python. Here is the code that I'm using but it doesn't work. I want to find all pixels with a yellow color.

```
from PIL import Image
def find_rgb(imagename, r_query, g_query, b_query):
    img = Image.open(imagename)
    rgb = img.convert('RGB')
    for x in range(507):
        for y in range(337):
            r, g, b, = rgb.getpixel((x, y))
            if r >= r_query and g >= g_query and b <= b_query:
                return (x,y)
```

And how can you do it that Python only gives the coordinates if there are at least three pixels with the same color? (They mustn't be the exact same color, they can be for example 156,173,87 and 155,173,87.)

Comment: What exaclty doesn't work ? did you get an error or did you not find the pixels ?

Comment: It only showed one coordinate each time i tried and it was always the same coordinate.

Comment: Try replacing ``return`` with ``yield``. With the former, you only get a single return value as the function is finished with the first match. The latter continues to search and ultimately creates a generator containing all found pixels. The generator can be converted with ``list(find_rgb(imagename, r_query, g_query, b_query))``

Answer (score 4):

For speed reasons I would recommend using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

width = 100
height = 100
channels = 3
img = np.random.rand(width, height, channels) * 255

r=0
g=1
b=2

r_query = 240
g_query = 240
b_query = 20
print(np.where((img[:,:,r] >= r_query) & (img[:,:,g] >= g_query) & (img[:,:,b] <= b_query)))
```

This gives you a 2D-Array with the coordinates of the yellow pixels in your original image.

Comment: Should you download numpy or is it already installed in python?

Comment: You need to download it. Best with conda or pip.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `return` in the loop, so you will always have max one pixel returned, you can store the pixels in a `set` in order to return all yellow pixels.

```
def find_yellow_pixels(image_name):

    # Set the value you want for these variables
    r_min = 250
    r_max = 255
    g_min = 250
    g_max = 255
    b_min = 0
    b_max = 0

    yellow_pixels = set()

    img = Image.open(image_name)
    rgb = img.convert('rgb')
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            r, g, b = rgb.getpixel((x, y))
            if r >= r_min and r <= r_max and b >= b_min and b <= b_max and g >= g_min and g <= g_max:
                yellow_pixels.add((x,y))

    return yellow_pixels
```

**Edit**: fix, `open(` to `Image.open(`

Comment: When I try it, it gives me the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#137>", line 1, in <module>
    find_yellow_pixels('t1.jpg')
  File "<pyshell#136>", line 14, in find_yellow_pixels
    rgb = img.convert('rgb')
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'convert'

Comment: Yeap, there was a mistake, it is fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
from PIL import Image
def find_rgb(imagename, r_query, g_query, b_query):
    img = Image.open(imagename)
    pix = img.load()
    coordinates= []
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            r, g, b = pix[x,y]
            if matching_algo(r, g, b, r_query, g_query, b_query):
                # print("{},{} contains {}-{}-{} ".format(x, y, r, g, b))
                coordinates.append((x, y))
    return(coordinates)


def matching_algo(r, g, b, r_query, g_query, b_query):
    if r == r_query and g == g_query:
        return True
    elif r == r_query and b == b_query:
        return True
    elif b == b_query and g == g_query:
        return  True
    else:
        return False


if __name__== "__main__":
    find_rgb('dead_parrot.jpg', 255, 255, 0)
```

Give this a try, you can improve my matching algorithm implementation.
I removed your convert() code and used load() instead

Comment: I mixed this and the previous one and it worked for me. Thanks!